# A question on MathHelper.ToRadians();

Tags: c#, xna, return-value

I assumed MathHelper.ToRadians() returns a value from 0° - 360° whereby:

- 0° NORTH
- 90° EAST
- 180° SOUTH
- 270° WEST

or is it:

- 0° EAST
- 90° NORTH
- 180° WEST
- 270° SOUTH

thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on which direction you're facing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MathHelper.ToRadians() accepts a value in degrees and returns its radian value.  As such, 0 = 0, 90 = pi/2, etc. with 0 being "east" and 90 being "north".

Comment: -1 you are free to interpret the angle however you please.  Whatever direction you are considering 0° to be, that will be the same direction as 0 radians.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context in an applied problem, mathematically, you can use either the map interpretation (0=north) or the usual math interpretation (0=east). All the trig properties will hold either way.

Based on Daniel's input, MathHelper, being a math program, apparently does any drawing using the Math interpretation, but all the math content would work equally in the map context.